# How to send SOAP request and Parse SOAP response in XML format in Android?

Tags: android, soap, xml-parsing, httpresponse

Am very new to Android apps development. In my new Android app i want to show some data from webservice. This means i have a `SOAP message`, i need to parse the data from SOAP response. In iPhone app i knew very well to parse SOAP message response but, in android i don't know how to do this? I searched lot in Google and get some ideas. But, am very confusing on this. Can anyone please suggest any easiest way to understand SOAP send request/receive response and parse(`XML format`) the response in `SAXParser` in `Android`? I has installed `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`in my project. Here i found some sample code, i post here,

```
import java.io.*;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;


public class ParsingSteps 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     try{
       // String msg="<hello>World!</hello>";
        String msg = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope " + "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://
www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope\" " + "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/
 2001/XMLSchema-instance <http://www.w3.org/%0A2001/XMLSchema-instance>\""
 +"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/
 XMLSchema\"& gt;" +
         "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
         "<result>" +
         "<message xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">Hello World</message>" +
        "</result>" +
        "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
        "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

      //  byte[] in= msg.getBytes();

        KXmlParser parser=new KXmlParser();
       parser.setInput(new StringReader(msg));
       SoapEnvelope soapenvelope= new SoapEnvelope
(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        //soapenvelope.parse(parser);
        soapenvelope.parseBody(parser);

          }
       catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("Error reading URI: " + e.getMessage ());
       } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
              System.out.println("Error in parsing: " + e.getMessage ());
       }
      //  String result=parser.getName();
       //System.out.println(result);
    }
 }
```

Is this correct code. Please give any suggestion on my question. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google for Ksoap2 tutorial u will get a lot of them . Here is sample code for sending request to web service .

```
public class WebServicePoc extends Activity{
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Arnoid";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Arnoid";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://ipaddress:port/UserAuthenticationInterfacer.asmx";
EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    HashMap<String, String> a=new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("FOSID", "1994");
        request.addProperty("IMEINumber", "");
        request.addProperty("SIMCardNo", "");
        request.addProperty("ApplicationName", "App");
        request.addProperty("CurrentVersion", "1.0.0.0");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        editText.setText(result.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And for xml pls check tutorial for xml parsers,use SAX only, as STAX is not supported in android . For sending xml request u can send xml as string and then decode on sever side .

Comment: Thanks lot for your response. I will incorporate your thought in my project. I want your help in future. Thanks.

Comment: How @Gopinath did you set the property in order to send the right message?