# how to parse the xsd schema in android

Tags: android, parsing, xsd

I am using soap webService and using that I have received the response which is in xsd schema format. I dont know how to parse it, I have tried the code but its not working,Can someone help me.

My Main Class is

```
public class Mylearning extends ListActivity {
    //ArrayList<cat> list = null;
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://yyy.mobi/GetLearningPortalsList";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME ="GetLearningPortalsList";
    private static final String NAMESPACE ="http://yyy.mobi/";
    private static final String URL = "http://webservices.yyy.mobi/MobileLMSServices.asmx";
    private Bundle bundleResult = new Bundle();
    private JSONObject JSONObj;
    private JSONArray JSONArr;
    //private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList;
    SoapObject request;
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;               
    ListView mainListView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylearning);

        //mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("SiteURL","http://www.yyy.mobi/");
        request.addProperty("PageID","1");
        request.addProperty("SearchText","");

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();   

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        SoapObject result = null;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport sab = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        sab.debug = true;
        try {
            sab.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            if (envelope.getResponse() != null) {
                result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                String[] values = new String[result.getPropertyCount()];
                int j = result.getPropertyCount();
                String repons=result.toString();
            //  Log.d("result",repons.toString());
                Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(repons);
                int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

                if((numResults <= 0)){
                    Toast.makeText(Mylearning.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    finish();
                }

                 NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
                    map.put("Course", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Course"));
                    map.put("Description", "Description:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Description"));
                    map.put("icon", "icon: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "icon"));
                    mylist.add(map);            
                }

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.rowmylearning, 
                        new String[] { "Course", "Description","icon" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.txt1, R.id.txt2,R.id.img1 });

                setListAdapter(adapter);
                final ListView lv = getListView();

                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                        Toast.makeText(Mylearning.this, "Course '" + o.get("Course") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                    }
                });

            }
        }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
}
```

My Xmlfunction class is

```
public class XMLfunctions {

    public final static Document XMLfromString(String repons){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(repons));
          //  Log.d("message",repons.toString());
            doc = db.parse(is);
            Log.d("doc", doc.toString());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;

    }

     public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node kid;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return kid.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }
    public static int numResults(Document doc){     
        Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
        int res = -1;

        try{
            res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
        }catch(Exception e ){
            res = -1;
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return XMLfunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767389/how-to-send-soap-request-and-parse-soap-response-in-xml-format-in-android)

You can use the [ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) a SOAP Client Library to parse Responses