# Right way of calling SOAP API using Ksoap2-Android with Kotlin?

Tags: soap, kotlin, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I would like to ask if this is the right way of calling SOAP API using Ksoap2 Library.

SOAP API address -

```
http://rtpi.dublinbus.ie/DublinBusRTPIService.asmx
```

XML REQUEST will be -

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <GetRealTimeStopData xmlns="http://dublinbus.ie/">
            <stopId>[int]</stopId>
            <forceRefresh>[boolean]</forceRefresh>
        </GetRealTimeStopData>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

My Kotlin Function is looking like this.

```
class SoapAsyncTask : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    var URL = "http://rtpi.dublinbus.ie/DublinBusRTPIService.asmx"
    var NAMESPACE = "http://dublinbus.ie/"
    var METHOD_NAME = "GetRealTimeStopData"

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String {
        var result = ""
        val soapObject = SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME)

        val propertyInfo = PropertyInfo()
        propertyInfo.type = Int::class.java
        propertyInfo.name = "stopId"
        propertyInfo.value = params[0].toInt()
        soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfo)

        val propertyInfo1 = PropertyInfo()
        propertyInfo1.type = Boolean::class.java
        propertyInfo1.name = "forceRefresh"
        propertyInfo1.value = true
        soapObject.addProperty(propertyInfo1)

        val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11)
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject)
        envelope.dotNet = false

        val httpTransportSE = HttpTransportSE(URL)

        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(getSoapAction(METHOD_NAME), envelope)
            Log.wtf("** DEBUG ** envelope.response ", envelope.response.toString())
            var resultObject: SoapObject = envelope.response as SoapObject
            Log.wtf("** DEBUG ** resultObject ", resultObject.toString())
           
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return result

    }

    override fun onPostExecute(s: String) {
        Log.wtf("** DEBUG **", s)
    }

    private fun getSoapAction(method: String): String {
        return "\"" + NAMESPACE + method + "\""
    }

}
```

Is this right way of calling SOAP API? I got empty response somehow.
Am I missing something in here?

Log Info

```
2019-05-03 16:04:12.816 17378-17406/com.jinsoft77.soaptest E/** DEBUG ** envelope.response: anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{}; }
2019-05-03 16:04:12.822 17378-17406/com.jinsoft77.soaptest E/** DEBUG ** resultObject: anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{}; }
```

XML what I am supposed to get as result will be look like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetRealTimeStopDataResponse xmlns="http://dublinbus.ie/">
            <GetRealTimeStopDataResult>
                <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="StopData" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="StopData">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ServiceDelivery_Status" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ServiceDelivery_MoreData" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="StopMonitoringDelivery_Version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredCall_VisitNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="LineNote" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                    <DocumentElement xmlns="">
                        <StopData diffgr:id="StopData1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>bac</ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>
                            <ServiceDelivery_Status>true</ServiceDelivery_Status>
                            <ServiceDelivery_MoreData>false</ServiceDelivery_MoreData>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>1.0</StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef />
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>1259</MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>Outbound</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>2019-05-03</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>3455</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>bac</MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>2355</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>Jobstown via City Centre</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>true</MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>false</MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>27113</MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>43065</MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>
                            <MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>6</MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>
                            <MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>false</MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:14:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:14:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:14:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:14:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>
                            <Timestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.43+01:00</Timestamp>
                            <LineNote />
                        </StopData>
                        <StopData diffgr:id="StopData2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                            <ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>bac</ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>
                            <ServiceDelivery_Status>true</ServiceDelivery_Status>
                            <ServiceDelivery_MoreData>false</ServiceDelivery_MoreData>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>1.0</StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef />
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>1259</MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>Outbound</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>2019-05-03</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>3441</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>bac</MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>2355</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>Jobstown via City Centre</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>true</MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>false</MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>27111</MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>43063</MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>
                            <MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>6</MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>
                            <MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>false</MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:24:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:24:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:24:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:24:33+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>
                            <Timestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.43+01:00</Timestamp>
                            <LineNote />
                        </StopData>
                        <StopData diffgr:id="StopData3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
                            <ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>bac</ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>
                            <ServiceDelivery_Status>true</ServiceDelivery_Status>
                            <ServiceDelivery_MoreData>false</ServiceDelivery_MoreData>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>1.0</StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef />
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>1259</MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>Outbound</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>2019-05-03</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>3447</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>bac</MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>2355</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>Jobstown via City Centre</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>true</MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>false</MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>27112</MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>43060</MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>
                            <MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>6</MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>
                            <MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>false</MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:35:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:35:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:35:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:35:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>
                            <Timestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.447+01:00</Timestamp>
                            <LineNote />
                        </StopData>
                        <StopData diffgr:id="StopData4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
                            <ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>bac</ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>
                            <ServiceDelivery_Status>true</ServiceDelivery_Status>
                            <ServiceDelivery_MoreData>false</ServiceDelivery_MoreData>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>1.0</StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef />
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>1259</MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>Outbound</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>2019-05-03</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>3746</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>bac</MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>2355</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>Jobstown via City Centre</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>true</MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>false</MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>27002</MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>44543</MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>
                            <MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>6</MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>
                            <MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>false</MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:45:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:45:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:45:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:45:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>
                            <Timestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.447+01:00</Timestamp>
                            <LineNote />
                        </StopData>
                        <StopData diffgr:id="StopData5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
                            <ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>bac</ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>
                            <ServiceDelivery_Status>true</ServiceDelivery_Status>
                            <ServiceDelivery_MoreData>false</ServiceDelivery_MoreData>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>1.0</StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef />
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>1259</MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>Outbound</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>2019-05-03</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>3479</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>bac</MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>2355</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>Jobstown via City Centre</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>true</MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>false</MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>27004</MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>44541</MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>
                            <MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>6</MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>
                            <MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>false</MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:55:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T16:55:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:55:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T16:55:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>
                            <Timestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.447+01:00</Timestamp>
                            <LineNote />
                        </StopData>
                        <StopData diffgr:id="StopData6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
                            <ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</ServiceDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>bac</ServiceDelivery_ProducerRef>
                            <ServiceDelivery_Status>true</ServiceDelivery_Status>
                            <ServiceDelivery_MoreData>false</ServiceDelivery_MoreData>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>1.0</StopMonitoringDelivery_Version>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</StopMonitoringDelivery_ResponseTimestamp>
                            <StopMonitoringDelivery_RequestMessageRef />
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>2019-05-03T16:06:40.137+01:00</MonitoredStopVisit_RecordedAtTime>
                            <MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>1259</MonitoredStopVisit_MonitoringRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_LineRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>Outbound</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DirectionRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>2019-05-03</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DataFrameRef>
                            <FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>3486</FramedVehicleJourneyRef_DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>27</MonitoredVehicleJourney_PublishedLineName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>bac</MonitoredVehicleJourney_OperatorRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>2355</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>Jobstown via City Centre</MonitoredVehicleJourney_DestinationName>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>true</MonitoredVehicleJourney_Monitored>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>false</MonitoredVehicleJourney_InCongestion>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>27006</MonitoredVehicleJourney_BlockRef>
                            <MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>44545</MonitoredVehicleJourney_VehicleRef>
                            <MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>6</MonitoredCall_VisitNumber>
                            <MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>false</MonitoredCall_VehicleAtStop>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T17:05:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>2019-05-03T17:05:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedArrivalTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T17:05:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_AimedDepartureTime>
                            <MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>2019-05-03T17:05:08+01:00</MonitoredCall_ExpectedDepartureTime>
                            <Timestamp>2019-05-03T16:06:40.46+01:00</Timestamp>
                            <LineNote />
                        </StopData>
                    </DocumentElement>
                </diffgr:diffgram>
            </GetRealTimeStopDataResult>
        </GetRealTimeStopDataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I used Java code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22402261/826946. It interoperates fine with Kotlin